# Запись в открытый файл

Tags: c++, fstream

можно ли сделать такое: у меня есть созданный файл `text.txt`, я сперва его открываю, а затем запускаю программу, далее пишу какую либо строку в файл, например слово `Hello`, в ответ на это программа справа от этого слова пишет 'Hello | OK!'. То есть в реальном времени считывает мою строку и добавляет к ней `| OK!` или `| Bad!` (в зависимости от строки). Я хочу, что бы результат после ввода сразу отобразился справа от строки и мне не пришлось бы закрыть файл, чтобы увидеть результат.
Заранее спасибо.

P.S По прошлому опыту всегда приходилось закрывать файл (обновить), чтобы увидеть результат работы программы. Кода моих попыток нет, т.к я даже примерно не знаю с чего начать.

Comment: непонятно, где должен отобразиться результат после ввода

Comment: В открытом файле, куда я написал строку, результат справа от этой строки.

Comment: Только вам нужен инструмент, который пишет точно в тот файл, что открыт. Впрочем, `echo Hello... >text.txt` из соседенего терминала (и `tail -f text.txt` еще из одного) вполне сгодиться.

Comment: Я бы хотел записывать не из терминалов в файл (Вообще предполагалось на винде ), а, например, с помощью windows-кого блокнота, т.е открываю файл text.txt с помощью блокнота, затем как только я написал один символ, мой код начал работать и напротив символа написал бы мне | BAD, далее я пишу ещё символ, и мне отпять справа | BAD, и так пока я в итоге не напишу слово Hello, когда программа считала эту строку, она справа от неё пишет | OK

Comment: Программа, в которой происходит редактирование, должна в таком случае следить за файлом и перезагружать его при наличии изменений.
Не все редакторы так умеют - например, Notepad++ это поддерживает, а Блокнот - нет